# Unable to execute script using user_data

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to execute a script once while ec2 boots up so have following in instance.tf.

```
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
ami = "i-33434"
user_data = "${data.template_file.user-data.rendered}"
}
data "template_file" "user-data" {
template = "${file("templates/init.tpl")}"}
```

And have init.tpl file created under templates folder with below content:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir /ecs
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdt10
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdt11
mkdir /ecs/folder1
mkdir /ecs/folder2
mount /dev/xvdt10 /ecs/folder1
mount /dev/xvdt11 /ecs/folder2
echo /dev/xvdt10  /ecs/folder1 ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2 >> /etc/fstab
echo /dev/xvdt11  /ecs/folder2 ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2 >> /etc/fstab
```

Comment: What is instead shown in the instance log?

Comment: @StephenKing - Sorry, where do I see instance log? I'm new to this. Nothing showing under /var/log

Comment: `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` and `/var/log/cloud-init.log`

Comment: Also [in the AWS console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output).

Comment: system log does not showing anything around this issue.

Comment: So what's actually the problem? You say "Unable to execute". What's working, what not?

Comment: sorry mate, let me come back with more details.